# how to cancel only parent tasks when cancelling child tasks?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, task, cancellationtokensource

I'we got an async controller action  with cancellation token as a parameter:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string NomenCode = "", string ProducerName = "", bool? WithAnalog = null, long? OrderId = null, CancellationToken cancelToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
// .. some code

// my async method gets this token
await SearchModel.GetRemains(search, NomenCode, ProducerName, _WithAnalog,     this.HttpContext, cancelToken);

//.. more code
}
```

`SearchModel.GetRemains` method calls 3 other async methods(web-services) and when one of them gets cancelled by a timeout, the others are not executing.

In every one of that 3 web services I connect to database also asyncronously. How can I make 2 of my `async` tasks work when third one's `async` child method gets an error?

I pass cancellation token parameter to all `async` methods from the parent method.

And if I don't want a child action to effect on my parent action's execution at all? But want it to cancell if parent was cancelled? What should I do?

Thanks for your attention and help

Comment: Where are the three async methods being invoked?

Comment: somewhere inside SearchModel.GetRemains()

Comment: List<Task<SearchRemainsData>> tasks = new List<Task<SearchRemainsData>>();

                    Task<SearchRemainsData> t = new SearchMethodEmex().GetResult(searchParam);
                    tasks.Add(t);
                    Task<SearchRemainsData> t = new SearchMethodStells().GetResult(searchParam);
                    tasks.Add(t);
                    Task<SearchRemainsData> t = new SearchMethodMikado().GetResult(searchParam);
                    tasks.Add(t);
       

                await this.HandleTasks(tasks, cToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make 2 of my async tasks work when third one's async child method gets an error?

When a task is canceled or completes with an error (such as a timeout), then `await`ing that task will raise an exception.

To avoid propagating the exception, just use `try`/`catch`:

```
try
{
  await SearchModel.GetRemains(search, NomenCode, ProducerName, _WithAnalog,     this.HttpContext, cancelToken);
}
catch (MyExpectedException)
{
  ...
}
```

> But want it to cancell if parent was cancelled?

You are already passing the parent's `CancellationToken` down, so this is already taken care of. The same cancellation token is shared between the parent and all of its children.